# Is there a drop-in replacement for Java Stack that is not synchronized?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have a large codebase (written by me) that uses the Stack data structure. This was used for convenience and I am using it as Stack sometimes or Vector/List some other times.

After a performance review however it was decided that we do not want to pay extra for the synchronization safety. I need now to replace this structure with a non-synchronized one (and it is mentioned a lot of times in the code).

I was happy to discover that Apache collections includes an [ArrayStack](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.html) which is exactly what I want (same as Java stack but non-synchronized). However this does NOT have generics as modern Java 5 code (which is what I use). And I am not going to convert my code to look like Java 1.4

So is there any other Java 5 compliant drop-in replacement for Java Stack or do I need to write my own?

**Update:**

I used LinkedList with tuned "pop"/"push" methods.

Comment: Like Jon Skeet said, ArrayDeque is the way to go. BTW, ArrayStack is broken in the same sense as Stack, as ArrayStack inherits from ArrayList, which is a good example of a bad use of inheritance ;-).

Comment: By the way, if you're using a modern HotSpot JVM, there is a good chance that it has optimized away the locks for you. For example, it has already made the transition from `StringBuffer` (synchronized) to `StringBuilder` (non-synchronized) largely unnecessary (although it still has its place).

Comment: @Adam Yes I know, but try explaining that to the client!

Comment: @kazanaki: Fair enough. By the way, who conducted this "performance review" that you must now adhere to? A consulting firm? Do you know as to whether or not they *measured* the performance of the existing application to guide their recommendations?

Comment: @Adam The review was performed by the client. Don't ask...

Comment: @kazanaki: You have my sympathy. :)

Comment: FWIW: Sonar/Findbugs complains about unnecessary synchronization in these classes, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say "Java 5 compliant" - [`ArrayDeque<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) didn't arrive until Java 6, but sounds like what you're after (using the `Deque<T>` interface where appropriate, of course). You can use it as a stack when you want to, or a queue where that's more appropriate... just call the appropriate methods, basically.

Comment: In Java 5.0, you can use `LinkedList<E>` with `add(0, E)` for push and `remove(0)` for pop.

Comment: @Peter: I agree. It's just a shame to rely on a concrete type. :(

Comment: @Peter I will probably do what you say. If you want, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it! Otherwise Sir Jon Skeet gets all the glory!

Comment: @Peter: I considered mentioning LinkedList, but suspected that the OP wanted the (partial) cache coherency of an array-based solution. But yes, LinkedList will work too.

Comment: @kazanaki: Does this mean that you're stuck with *precisely* Java 5 and not Java 6? It would be a shame to go through the effort of replacing all your `Stack`s with another concrete class like `LinkedList`. Coding to an interface would be nicer, in my opinion.

Comment: @kazanaki, You can use List<E> as the interface as this will work with any list. However for ArrayList<E> to work efficiently you have to add/remove from the end. (This is faster than using LinkedList but uglier) `add(e)` for push and `remove(list.size()-1)` for pop.

Comment: @Adam Paynter: LinkedList implements both Queue and Deque. No need to rely on a concrete type.

Comment: @barjak: That is correct *in Java 6*. In Java 5, it did not implement `Deque`. That is why I asked kazanaki if he was strictly limited to Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

In your special case (and actually only in such a case), I'd simply *copy and paste* the Stack class from an open source Java SE implementation into your own package, and remove all synchronized keywords. You may want to add `extends java.util.Stack`. Now you'll only have to change the import declarations in your code.

I do realize, that *typically* it's not a good idea to copy code, but here's why this doesn't apply to this case:

- If the the `pop()` and `push()` semantics of a Stack fit well for the current code, then this doesn't change just because of performance considerations. The semantics of a deque or linked list are different (they allow to add/remove from both sides).
- The synchronization overhead of `java.util.Stack` cannot be removed by another technique like subclassing (calling `super` methods) or delegation.
- It's better to copy *well tested* code (as far as the license allows it), than to rewrite from scratch.

In general, it would be a lot better to use `java.util.Stack` as if it were an interface, and not to use `new Stack()` in the code, but to instantiate it by using factories.

Comment: copyright must be respected. in general it's a bad idea to copy code, especially from Oracle:) And it's a "stack", anyone should be able to write one from scratch.

Comment: @irreputable: That's why I said explicitly "from an **open source** Java SE implementation" (and I mean e.g. Apache Harmony). Of course, it's still necessary to respect the license, but if you do, you may copy it.